# Problem playing media from raw resource through MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

I created the soundboard and the code compiles, it just wont create any sounds or play the mp3, where am I coding it wrong as it does not start anywhere.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    public class Bluarg extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        MediaPlayer mp1;
        MediaPlayer mp2;
        MediaPlayer mp3;
        MediaPlayer mp4;
        MediaPlayer mp5;
        MediaPlayer mp6;
        MediaPlayer mp7;
        MediaPlayer mp8;
        MediaPlayer mp9;
        MediaPlayer mp10;
        MediaPlayer mp11;
        MediaPlayer mp12;
        MediaPlayer mp13;
        MediaPlayer mp14;
        MediaPlayer mp15;
        MediaPlayer mp16;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb1);
            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb2);
            mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb3);
            mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb4);
            mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb5);
            mp6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb6);
            mp7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb7);
            mp8 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb8);
            mp9 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb9);
            mp10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb10);
            mp11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb11);
            mp12 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb12);
            mp13 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb13);
            mp14 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb14);
            mp15 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb15);
            mp16 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deb16);



            final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);
            final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
            button3.setOnClickListener(this);
            final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
            button4.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05);
            button5.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06);
            button6.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
            button7.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08);
            button8.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button09);
            button9.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
            button10.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
            button11.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button12);
            button12.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button13);
            button13.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button14);
            button14.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button15);
            button15.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button16);
            button16.setOnClickListener (this);

            final Button button17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button17);
            button17.setOnClickListener (this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Button02:
                mp1.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Button03:
                mp2.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Button04:
                mp3.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Button05:
                mp4.start();
                break;  
            case R.id.Button06:
                mp5.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Button07:
                mp6.start();
                break;     
            case R.id.Button08:
                mp7.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Button09:
                mp8.start();
                break;     
            case R.id.Button10:
                mp9.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Button11:
                mp10.start();
                break; 
            case R.id.Button12:
                mp11.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Button13:
                mp12.start();
                break;    
            case R.id.Button14:
                mp13.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Button15:
                mp14.start();
                break;    
            case R.id.Button16:
                mp15.start();
                break; 
            case R.id.Button17:
                mp16.start();
                break;    
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            mp1.release();
            mp2.release();
            mp3.release();
            mp4.release();
            mp5.release();
            mp6.release();
            mp7.release();
            mp8.release();
            mp9.release();
            mp10.release();
            mp11.release();
            mp12.release();
            mp13.release();
            mp14.release();
            mp15.release();
            mp16.release();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: have you been able to step through it with the debugger on?  Is the app force closing or even starting?

Comment: it opens fine, runs through clean code, buttons click just no click event i guess.  and Activity2 is like a splash screen eventually i will use a timer to switch from the starting splash to this screen where i will have all the buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this be an issue when you create too many MediaPlayer objects. You have a *lot* of redundant code in here. Aside from using some loops to cut away 90% of your code, try using something like this for your MediaPlayers instead of the way you currently have it:

```
//outside onCreate(), where you have your MPs now
MediaPlayer mp;
Resources resources;

//inside onCreate()
mp = new MediaPlayer();
resources = getResources();

int[] rawIds = {
    R.raw.deb1, R.raw.deb2,
    R.raw.deb3, R.raw.deb4,
    R.raw.deb5, R.raw.deb6,
    R.raw.deb7, R.raw.deb8,
    R.raw.deb9, R.raw.deb10,
    R.raw.deb11, R.raw.deb12,
    R.raw.deb13, R.raw.deb14,
    R.raw.deb15, R.raw.deb16 
};

int[] buttonIds = {
    R.id.Button02, R.id.Button03,
    R.id.Button04, R.id.Button05,
    R.id.Button06, R.id.Button07,
    R.id.Button08, R.id.Button09,
    R.id.Button10, R.id.Button11,
    R.id.Button12, R.id.Button13,
    R.id.Button14, R.id.Button15,
    R.id.Button16, R.id.Button17 
};

//this can replace your whole Button assignment portion
for (int i : buttonIds) {
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(i);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//in your onClick(). Might be a better way to do this than looping through
//all of the ids, but this should still be quick, and much less code.
for (int i = 0, i < buttonIds.length; i++) {

    //if the button being clicked is e.g. Button02...
    if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {

        //get the file descriptor for your Raw Resource associated with Button02...
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = resources.openRawResourceFd(rawIds[i]);

        //in case it's not in the ready state...
        mp.reset();

        //and set the mediaPlayer's data source, prepare it, and begin
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: im not sure how to implement that into the code i keep getting errors trying to run that through.

Comment: You're going to have to get a lot more specific. If you're getting a force close, open your LogCat window to figure out what Exception is being thrown, and it will also show you on what line in your file it occurs. If you read the comments, I'm telling you exactly where in your code to put it. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Wait, I just did a double take. Why do you have an Activity within an Activity? Your `implements OnClickListener`, along with all of your `Bluarg` code should only be in a single Activity. In this instance, your `SplashActivity`. Obviously, it's working enough that you're seeing the buttons and all (because you're calling `setContentView`, but nothing in your inner Activity will ever even happen, to my knowledge, as it's never "started".

Comment: sorry im new to droid, i started c++ in college but never got to touch JAVA and mainly stuck to .net so im trying to adjust i will restart the entire code all in one activity and drop the second activity and see how much that helps thank you so much for the advice

Comment: No prob! I think that might be your issue, actually. You still might have issues just in your original code just because of so many media player initializations, but I think the second Activity may be what's causing your buttons to never be initialized.